# Can settlers wear power armor?

Tags: fallout-4

I am building a settlement and I want to know if settlers can wear **power armor**. If so, can they take the power armor if the power armor is on display on a power armor rack?

Comment: They can; see Vemonus' answer. Generally speaking, you want to prevent them from using your power armor at all costs. In addition to them wandering off with the power armor, if they get into a fight, the pieces of the power armor (e.g. the helm) break MUCH faster when they're being used by an NPC as opposed to you using it normally. One raider invasion can scrap an entire suit of armor if you're unlucky.

Comment: Since the Settlers are invulnerable, there is no point of giving them power armor access.

Comment: @Nelson settlers are most definitely **not** invulnerable. See [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72829352). If you are not there to defend the settlement with them when it is attacked, they can be killed offscreen.

Comment: @Vemonus technically true, but this is an additional reason to make sure they are not in power armor. If you're far away, they'll die and disappear with your armor. If you're close, they're invulnerable.  My main point is don't stick settlers in PA unless you don't care about it.

Comment: @Nelson, I haven't left a fusion core outside of my inventory since I lost the T-45 pieces at the beginning of my first playthrough. Also, just because the settlers can't die doesn't mean the power armor pieces won't get broken. They just can't die.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. They tend to do it without your consent if you happen to leave fusion cores in your power armor. If you've never had this happen, you are unbelievably lucky.

To answer your question: "Can they take the power armor if they are on the power armor racks/stands?"

Based on [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136906129586/):

> As topic says, we were invaded and **a settler stole my suit of power armor off the rack it was on**

Based on later posts by OP, he had left a fusion core in the suit:

> the settler left the suit there with about 5 charge left in the core

So, as implied earlier, unless you want to lose your power armor with no warning, **take the fusion cores out of your power armor.**

Comment: After a settler wandered off with my best set of power armor (at the time anyway), I started removing all fusion cores. It's just easier, and they don't take up inventory weight!

Comment: OK another question so can they take the power armor if they are on the power armor racks/stands

Comment: You can also command settlers to get into power armor if you so desire. Companions too (human ones).

Comment: @Robert__garnet I edited my answer as well as your question to accommodate for the question you asked in your comment.

Comment: I use to take the fusion cores out when I first started playing for fear of this, but after a while I stopped caring, and yet, in over 200 hours of playtime I haven't ever had a settler hop into a power armor.

Comment: @TaylorAllred within my first 10 hours of playing, I found out the hard way when that T-45 from the rooftop of the museum was suddenly gone from Red Rocket and the frame was empty a ways away.

Comment: @TimmyJim You can't do that in the base game.  You must have a mod active.

Comment: Which part can't you do? I don't have any mods.

Comment: @Nelson, I've never tried because it would be a total waste, but I think you are able to command/assign a settler to wear power armor.

Comment: You cannot.  That's outright not possible.  I have deliberately tried when I have suits all over the place, and vanilla FO4 don't let you assign settlers to a suit.

Comment: I am unable to assign settlers to a suit on command.  You need to outline the exact steps you're doing it.  I know the settlement interface **says** assign, but it does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, based on [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/492378806380007254/), it looks like @Nelson is right.